# How to download a file forced to download from a php script in java?

Tags: java, php, download, force-download

I have php script on my server which forces a download when a correct key is given. I want to download the file which that script forces to download, not the script itself, using java. I see questions which answer how to download a file which is located at a certain url, but not how to download a file forced through a script. Also would it be possible to route the download through a certain path instead of having it go to the downloads folder of the computer, or wherever it would automatically go? Here's my relevant php script:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . str_replace(" ", "_", $arrRES['file']) . "\"");                    
echo $strFile;
```

and the java would be something like :

```
URL url= new URL("http://supremesharkbot.com:8080/update/?key="+activationkey);
```

but then i don't know where to go from there. Thanks

Comment: No you can't tell the browser where to save the file on a client PC, that's under the control of the user of that client PC to prevent nasty people from writing scripts to download virusey type things, or overwriting your critical system files

Comment: Ok so that's not the most important issue, i figure you probably can't tell it where to save the file. But how do you download it from the script in the first place? @MarkBaker

Comment: Welll in PHP, [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is the most obvious method to do so

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is here:

```
echo $strFile;
```

I would advise using `file_get_contents()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$strFile = file_get_contents($arrRES['file']);
echo $strFile;
```

I would also offer headers that fit the bill better for each file type. Don't try to force a download, let the user or their preference determine ho9w to handle the file. Can make the file type more general so the browser will prompt more often:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . str_replace(" ", "_", $arrRES['file']) . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($arrRES['file']));
$strFile = file_get_contents($arrRES['file']);
echo $strFile;
```